# issue to pass arraylist from an intent to another

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, hashmap

Before asking here, i first search how to pass an arraylist from an intent to another. Thanks to one of the post made on SO, I thought i found a way to do so.

The thing is, when i try to display the elements from the arraylist of my target activity, i only get one of the numerous elements i originally have in my departure activity.

To put it in clear, here is my code in my fisrt activity :

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String,String>();

map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key2","value2");

arrayList.add(map);
Log.d("arrayList", String.valueOf(arrayList));
```

In the logcat, I have the expected elements :

```
D/arrayList:: [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2","value2"}
```

Then, i pursue with this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirstActivity.this,MySecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("arrayList",arrayList);
```

Now, this is my second activity where should be the received elements.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
arrayList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayList");
Log.d("arraySecondActivity", String.valueOf(arrayList));
```

In the logcat, only my second item is display :

```
D/arraySecondActivity: [{key2=value2}]
```

and i don't know why ... does someone maybe know ?

thanks !

Comment: make sure your item has been added to your arraylist before you are passing it via intent

Comment: how ? I mean, how come my second item is okay while the first one is not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**intent.putExtra("arrayList",arrayList);** this wrong in your code.
Serializable the arraylist before pass like below

Try this code

```
 ArrayList<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();
 Intent intent = new Intent(Current.class, next.class);
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)object);
 intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
 startActivity(intent);
```

In the next.class

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
 ArrayList<Object> object = (ArrayList<Object>)  args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. I got the same result as before.

Comment: make sure your item has been added to your arraylist

Comment: in my firstActivity, i made sure that my two items appear in my arraylist via logcat, for i thought that there was the problem ... but my two items are displayed there ... my main problem is i don't get why my second item is well displayed in my second activity, whereas my first one is not ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose **strinclude** is a simple arraylist of integers.

```
ArrayList<Integer> strinclude=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**Activity 1:**

```
//Here I am sending the arraylist to Activity2
 Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("include",strinclude);
startActivity(i);
```

**Activity 2:**

```
  //Here I am recieving the arraylist from Activity1
ArrayList<Integer> strinclude=new ArrayList<Integer>();
strinclude=(ArrayList<Integer>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("include");
```

Thats it.